# Checkbox updating subract quantity codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem with checkboxes when I select one of them. How do I stop the foreach from running if a checkbox has not been checked? Please check my code to fix the issue.

***i want a condition for data unchecked.***

**This is my controller:**

```
public function create_cargo_manifest(){
   $core_model = new Core_m;
   $core_model->save_cargo_details();

   redirect('core/cargo_lookup/','refresh');
}
```

**This is my model:**

```
function save_cargo_details() {
    $data = array();

    $waybillno = $this->input->post('waybillno');
    $quantity = $this->input->post('quantity');
    $waybilldate = $this->input->post('waybilldate');
    $declared_value = $this->input->post('declared_value');
    $consignee = $this->input->post('consignee');

    $count = count($waybillno);

    if(empty($waybillno)){

    }else{
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $data = array(
                'waybillno' => $waybillno[$i],
                'quantity' => $quantity[$i],
                'waybilldate' => $waybilldate[$i],
                'declared_value' => $declared_value[$i],
                'consignee' => $consignee[$i],

            );
            // SUBRACT REMAINING_QUANTITY //
            $this->db->select('wd.remaining_qty');
            $this->db->where('wd.waybillno',$waybillno[$i]);
            $this->db->from(self::WAYBILL_DETAILS_TABLE. " as wd");
            $query = $this->db->get()->row();
            $qty = $query->remaining_qty; 

            $remaining = $qty - $data['quantity'];


            $this->db->where('waybillno',$waybillno[$i]);
            $this->db->set('remaining_qty',$remaining);
            $this->db->update(self::WAYBILL_DETAILS_TABLE);
             // INSERT DATA //
            $this->db->insert('sys_cargodetails', $data);

        }
    }
}
```

**This is my view:**

```
<?php foreach($waybill_header as $waybill_header) { ?>
   <?php echo form_open('core/create_cargo_manifest'); ?>
<tr style="text-align: center;">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="waybillno[]" value="<?php echo $waybill_header->waybillno; ?>"></td>
    <td><?php echo $waybill_header->waybillno; ?><input type="hidden" ></td>
    <td><?php echo $waybill_header->waybilldate; ?><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $waybill_header->waybilldate; ?>" name="waybilldate[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5" value="<?php echo $waybill_header->remaining_qty; ?>" name="quantity[]">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $waybill_header->declared_value; ?>" name="declared_value[]">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $waybill_header->consignee; ?>" name="consignee[]">
    </td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
</table>
     <input type="submit" value="Save"><button id="button_cancel" type="button">Close</button> 
<?php form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: and what's the issue exactly?

Comment: but what's the problem with the code? do you get any errors? is the database not updating? have you done any debugging whatsoever?

Comment: How do I stop the foreach from running if a checkbox has not been checked.

Comment: unchecked checkboxes won't pass through `$_POST`, so that's not the issue, I believe the problem is that you don't have a relationship between the fields, I would change the name attributes like this: `item[0][waybillno],item[0][waybilldate]` etc then you'd have all your data inside `$this->input->post('item')` that you can loop using  `foreach` and then check `if(isset($item['waybillno']))` to see if the checkbox was selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your arrays of `$waybillno[]`,`$quantity[]`,etc. are not related in any way so you can't assume that the values with the same index correspond to how they were submitted in the form, I would set the `name` attributes of the inputs so they form a single multi-dimensional array like this:

```
<?php echo form_open('core/create_cargo_manifest'); ?>
<table>
<?php foreach($waybill_header as $index => $waybill_header) { ?>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="headers[<?php echo $index?>][waybillno]" value="<?php echo $waybill_header->waybillno; ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $waybill_header->waybillno; ?><input type="hidden" >
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $waybill_header->waybilldate; ?>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $waybill_header->waybilldate; ?>" name="headers[<php echo $index?>][waybilldate]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="5" value="<?php echo $waybill_header->remaining_qty; ?>" name="headers[<?php echo $index?>][quantity]">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $waybill_header->declared_value; ?>" name="headers[<?php echo $index?>][declared_value]">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $waybill_header->consignee; ?>" name="headers[<?php echo $index?>][consignee]">
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Save"><button id="button_cancel" type="button">Close</button>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Then you'd need to update the model function like so:

```
function save_cargo_details() {
    $headers = $this->input->post('headers');

    foreach($headers as $header){
        if(isset($header['waybillno'])){//check for selected checkbox
            $data = array(
                'waybillno' => $header['waybillno'],
                'quantity' => $header['quantity'],
                'waybilldate' => $header['waybilldate'],
                'declared_value' => $header['declared_value'],
                'consignee' => $header['consignee'],
            );

            //UPDATE QUERY can be shortened to
            $this->db->where('waybillno',$header['waybillno']);
            $this->db->set('remaining_qty','remaining_qty-'.$header['quantity'],FALSE);
            $this->db->update(self::WAYBILL_DETAILS_TABLE);
            // INSERT DATA //
            $this->db->insert('sys_cargodetails', $data);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly
put your foreach inside following code

```
if(count($waybill_header)>0){
   //your foreach loop

}
```

Comment: i want to do is a condition for the data unchecked.

Comment: If a check box is not checked then the value of that chk box won't pass in $_POST/$_GET variables. If you need to pass the value for unchecked chk box use hidden form field of same name. And please give clear question and this guys will definitely help you.